# PC mic+audio to iPhone'ish plug

Tags: audio, iphone, microphone, adapter

I have a good headset with a mic which has a plug like that which is on the standard iPhone ear buds. In other words, one plug for both mic and audio.

I'd like to use this headset with my computer. Is there anything like a USB adapter or a 'iPhone plug to mic plug and audio plug'-splitter or something?

I've tried searching, but not really sure what this is even called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an adapter similar to this (3.5mm female to male usb): [http://www.amazon.com/GTMax-Female-Microphone-Adapter-Lanyard/dp/B0032AEF42](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032AEF42) .

Comment: That does look promising actually. Not sure what the neck strap is for though... :p

Comment: Now, how to get a hold of one of these in Norway... *sigh*

Comment: @svish I do not know how difficult that would be; but as posted above, it is just a '3.5mm female to usb male' adapter, so you could search for that.

Answer (score 3):

The Apple-jack :) is actually a TRRS (Tip-ring-ring-sleeve) 1/8th inch plug.

[image: TRRS Connector]

There are numerous adapters that will split out the two functions, [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00332DPDG) for example.

Apple has been known, however, to wire up their 1/8th inch jacks non-standard, making 3rd party adapters not work correctly.  Not sure if your headset in particular falls into this category, but just be aware.

From the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector) on TRS:

> Several mobile phones, particularly smartphones, feature 3.5 mm TRRS
>   connectors to facilitate attaching headphones/hands-free kits. 2
>   different forms are frequently found, both of which place left audio
>   on the tip and right audio on the first ring (mirroring the
>   configuration found on stereo connectors). Where they differ is in the
>   placement of the microphone and return contacts. The first, which
>   places the return signal on the second ring and the microphone on the
>   sleeve, is used by Apple's iPhone line, Samsung's Galaxy Nexus and
>   Nokia phones, among others. The second, which reverses these contacts,
>   is used by other Samsung smartphones and some Sony/Sony Ericsson
>   phones.

Answer (score -2):

Here ya go
http://www.showmecables.com/product/iPhone-Head-Set-Breakout-Cable-3-5mm-TRRS-Jack-to-Dual-3-5mm-Stereo-Plug-6-IN.aspx

Comment: This is not USB to jack, but jack male to jack 2 X female.